# What is Difference Between Polygon object detection vs Semantic Segmentation

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, image-segmentation

The output of Polygon object detection and Semantic Segmentation look kindda similar, former is a polygon around the objects and latter is pixels within such a polygon. So what is the difference in use cases of each?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Comment: Please see the NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/deep-learning/info